# Increase gcloud run deploy timeout (NOT request timeout)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

How to increase `gcloud run deploy` timeout (NOT request timeout)?

I know that I can do this FOR cloud build `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 900`

But my build takes a very long time, the cloud build keeps running but "gcloud run deploy" time out.

Comment: You can also set the request timeout during deployment using the command:`gcloud run deploy --image IMAGE\_URL --timeout=[TIMEOUT]`.You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout#setting)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya - That setting applies to HTTP request timeouts and not to deploy timeouts.

Comment: Edit your post and add details on what you are deploying and error messages. As written, I have no idea what you are deploying or why it might time out. You mention Cloud Build times out, but you also mention deploy. Build and deploy are separate steps. Also, do not use relative expressions like ***very long time***. Specify the actual time in seconds. If Cloud Build is failing, include the logs from Cloud Build in your post.

Comment: If `gcloud run deploy` is timing out, that means your container is taking too long to become ready and is failing the health check. Your solution is to redesign your container to not require long startup times. There is no setting to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the duration for the [startup probe](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks#configure-probes) **up to 240s (4 minutes)**. For that, you need to create a YAML file that you will deploy with the following command

```
gcloud run services replace <yaml file>
```

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: long-starts
  namespace: '<YOUR PEOJECT ID>'
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: long-starts-0005
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      containers:
        - image: <YOUR CONTAINER IMAGE>
          ports:
            - name: http1
              containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 512Mi
          startupProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 240
            periodSeconds: 240
            failureThreshold: 1
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8080
```

If you need more, you need to redesign your service: add more CPU/memory, load heavy components in background, split you service in multiple microservice, pre-load your component at container build time,...

Comment: Without specific details from the OP, I do not think this answer will help. If the container does not start and respond to requests within 4 minutes, the container is shut down. The Startup Probe has the same time limitation (four minutes). What might help is setting ***Startup CPU boost*** to provide more CPU performance to speed up container initialization. Another issue is that Cloud Run only queues requests for 10 seconds. That means initial requests will fail. My experience tells me the OP has an incorrect container design and none of these features/options will help.

Comment: Ohhhh, that's correct, the startup probe is limited to 240s! Thanks @JohnHanley, I updated my answer with that max limit